# Java - BigInter vs BitSet bitmask

Tags: java, biginteger, bitset, bitmask

I want to implement a Bitmask stored in a table in Mysql database.

Which is better, implementing it as a BigInterger to store bitmask as BIGINT  in mysql table

or BitSet to store bitmask as a VARCHAR ?

Comment: Also look into bitwise operators and bitmasks, as that's essentially what a `BitSet` is. [In fact, I've written a BitSet-like class before for enum ordinals](https://github.com/Codelanx/CodelanxCommons/blob/master/src/main/java/com/codelanx/commons/util/EnumBitSet.java), which is directly adaptable to just taking an integer location (0-63) instead if you change the method parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Since MySQLs `BIGINT` is a 64-bit signed integer value, you shouldn't use `BigInteger`, but `long` (or `Long` if nullable).

Since you're using it as a bitmask, which generally has a fixed size, a `BitSet` / `VARCHAR` doesn't seem like the right solution.

Even if you'd be using it as a set of flags, storing as a `long` / `BIGINT` would be better. It's easy to convert a `BitSet` to/from a `long` if needed for easier bit-manipulation in Java.

*My opinion:* You should use `long` / `BIGINT` for this.

Comment: You are right. Since bitmasks are of fixed size, it fits under Integer based representation. Based on this article https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html, I used UNSIGNED BIGINT db representation along with java BigInteger class. Thanks